# How do I read and print a generic internal table?

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I'm pretty new to this. I'm currently studying abap for my job and I have a problem that I can't seem to work out. How would I go about creating a Function Module that takes any kind of internal table and write it to the screen? I'm looking for a very generic solution that can work with any kind of internal table as input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the exact reason SAP has developed ALV (ABAP List Viewer).
One of the shortest way to display any (non-nested) table is the following.

```
  DATA: go_alv  TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table.

  CALL METHOD cl_salv_table=>factory
    IMPORTING
      r_salv_table = go_alv
    CHANGING
      t_table      = itab.

  go_alv->display( ).
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the simplest way for a table whose line type is only flat data objects, taken from page 33 of [This SAP Development Guide](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/60aa1742-0ef2-2c10-1592-84e1f99ad34e?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&46493021596920).

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <row> TYPE ANY,
               <comp> TYPE ANY.

LOOP AT itab INTO <row>.
  DO.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-index OF STRUCTURE <row> TO <wa_comp>.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      SKIP.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
    WRITE <wa_comp>.
  ENDDO.
ENDLOOP.
```

A more robust way would be to use introspection containing Run-Time Type Services, a set of classes that let you introspect the details of a data object.  This would give you the details mentioned by vwegert.  An even better option would be to put it in an ALV grid.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you have to think about a lot of stuff:

- column widths, dynamically sizing columns
- currency fields / fields with units
- date formatting in a multi-lingual environment
- tables may contain arbitrary data, including nested tables

All things considered, this is not a trivial task. This is best left to the [existing components](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/5e/88d440e14f8431e10000000a1550b0/frameset.htm).